# SlidesJS Hover pause function

Tags: jquery, html, hover, slideshow

im using SlideJS with a custom pagination here is the jquery call to the slideshow

```
$('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    });
```

i tired this

```
$(".next").mouseover(
            function () {
            stop();
            })
```

after the $('#slides').slides{('pause')}; just broke the slideshow and added a dozen pagination li's

http://www.slidesjs.com

i have added this and was able to get the player to stop but i havent figured out the play part. any idea?

```
$('#stop').mouseenter(function(){ clearInterval( $('#slides').data('interval'));
                });
$('#stop').mouseleave(function(){ playInterval ( $('#slides').data('interval', playInterval));  
                });
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: this helped but i still cannot get the show to pause on hover tried this $("#hoverHERE").bind('mouseover',function(){
     $('#slides').stop(true, false).animate({ width: "200px" });
     }, function() {
     $('#slides').stop(true, false).animate({ width: "100px" });
     });
to get to the div in question but when i switch it to $('#slides').slides('pause') as the function images disappear

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the stop play buttons to your advantage. Make sure you have that option turned on:

```
$(element).slidesjs({
    play: {
        active: true,
        auto: true
    }
});
```

I did this:

```
$(element).on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(".slidesjs-stop").click();
});

$(element).on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(".slidesjs-play").click();
});
```

Its a little brute force but works nicely.